# What is the correct way to reverse dict and access its values in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, mypy

While the following code perfectly prints out `c`, `b`, `a` `mypy` complains about it.

```
main.py:10: error: No overload variant of "reversed" matches argument types [typing.ValuesView[builtins.str*]]
```

What is the correct way to traverse `x` in reverse order and get the values?

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def main() -> None:
    x = OrderedDict([
        (1, 'a'),
        (2, 'b'),
        (3, 'c'),
    ])

    for y in reversed(x.values()):
        print(y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters iter doesn't work: https://repl.it/repls/SmoothMedicalNamebinding, `list` would probably turn the warning off. but the check is the issue, not the code

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: ah, no, indeed, reversed works on sequences, not iterators. *Doh*.

Comment: The bug is with the ordered dict view implementations, which don't inherit from `collections.abc.Reversible` (which is new in 3.6).

Comment: I see that typeshed does mark OrderedDict as reversible but not the views: https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/collections/__init__.pyi#L286-L292

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `OrderedDict` dictionary views do implement `__reversed__` but do not inherit from `collections.abc.Reversible` (the values view does inherit from `collections.abc.ValuesView`).

This could be fixed both by adding that base class in the Python standard library, and by updating the [Python Typeshed definition](https://github.com/python/typeshed). I've [filed an issue with the latter](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/2078), as that's the faster method to get you a fix.

You can clone my [pull-request](https://github.com/python/typeshed/pull/2079) branch to get the new definitions locally, then use the `--custom-typeshed-dir` switch to `mypy` to use it over the one compiled into mypy itself:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/mjpieters/typeshed.git \
    --branch ordereddict_views_reversible \
    ~/typeshed_ordereddict_views_reversible   # or a different location
mypy --custom-typeshed-dir ~/typeshed_ordereddict_views_reversible <yourproject>
```

Answer (score 1):

While it works on Python 3.6, on previous versions of Python 3, your code doesn't work. on python 3.4:

```
TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence
```

(has to do with the type of `dict.values()`)

One workaround is to convert to `list` first but that's wasteful.

```
for y in reversed(list(x.values())):
    print(y)
```

`mypy` isn't aware of that novelty (yet) and issues an error.

You should ignore that error. I didn't try it but maybe commenting with `# type: ignore` works (discussed in https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/500):

```
for y in reversed(list(x.values())):  # type: ignore
```